# Need help deciding on a taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, tags

I'm working on a project that mimics a product Catalog, all products belong to a *Collection* and they all have a *Type* and *Attributes*.

For instance, a shirt belongs to the Apparel Collection, so I created a Category called Collection and to which the Apparel Collection is a child.

Products have *types*, for instance a shirt is a type of product, a hat is another type of product, ideally I can group all the products of the same type together and filter accordingly, I'm using Tags for this, a tag 'shirt', another one 'jeans', etc.

My problem resides on the fact that Products can also have attributes or characteristics, for instance a shirt can be white or screen printed, a pair of jeans could have a particular style or color.

I want to filter my posts by Collection (Categories), Types (Tags) and Attributes (??) individually, which I can do up to Attributes, since I ran out of taxonomy?

What is the best way to tackle this issue? Is it a custom post type for Types, since they can be enumerated and move the attributes to tags?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest Apparel Collection as a custom post type. Shirts, Jeans etc as Categories. Colors, size, etc as tags.

That way, any body searching for only XL size can group all apparel with tag XL. You can further group per-apparel along with a tag. Should make your job easier.

Also, if you decide to create another collection, you can just create another custom post type for that as well. It will be cleaner in the back-end too.

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent my client from creating more Collections down the line?

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah.. I agree that it may limit your client's ability to create custom types for Collections. But that is something you can automate as well. But that will be tedious and unnecessary. It really depends on the client. Are they looking to expand their portfolio very often? Or do they sell a limited kind of products which you can create custom types for them right now? Because, any alternative that you may find to fix your problem using only tags and categories will limit your ability to sort/filter/list them based on criteria.

Comment: I think I'll solve it this way: -Tags for types, -Categories for Collections and a custom taxonomy for attributes, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yep. That should work too. :)